# Python: Joining and writing (XML.etrees) trees stored in a list

Tags: python, xml, tree, elementtree

I'm looping over some XML files and producing trees that I would like to store in a defaultdict(list) type. With each loop and the next child found will be stored in a separate part of the dictionary.

```
d = defaultdict(list)
counter = 0
for child in root.findall(something):
    tree = ET.ElementTree(something)
    d[int(x)].append(tree)
    counter += 1
```

So then repeating this for several files would result in nicely indexed results; a set of trees that were in position 1 across different parsed files and so on. The question is, how do I then join all of `d`, and write the trees (as a cumulative tree) to a file?

I can loop through the dict to get each tree:

```
for x in d:
    for y in d[x]:
        print (y)
```

This gives a complete list of trees that were in my dict. Now, how do I produce one massive tree from this?

[Sample input file 1](http://pastebin.com/5wC1pjvX)

[Sample input file 2](http://pastebin.com/GUYHWuhg)

[Required results from 1&2](http://pastebin.com/aJtD1xbb)

Given the apparent difficulty in doing this, I'm happy to accept more general answers that show how I can otherwise get the result I am looking for from two or more files.

Comment: why don't you just produce the tree as you go, instead of a defaultdict? the result will be very similar. a defaultdict has no natural transformation to an etree, so there are many choices you could make there, for example, what tags should the root tree all these trees are under use?

Comment: I'm actually parsing around 5 files that are being 'woven' together. There are around 2000 `something` elements in each, so the `something1` from `file1` is stored in the same place as `something1` from `file2` etc. The concept being that by storing it this way, there may be a method of traversing the dict so I can get all the `somethings` in correct order! Then put it all in one interleaved file!

Comment: Code updated after I sorted traversing the dict. So question now is how to take all of the trees that y produces to make one big tree?!

Comment: that is, in fact, the question. the simple solution is to create an Element, and add the trees as subelements, but not sure if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Same xml tree, please?

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - Can you rephrase your question please?

Comment: Sorry sample xml tree.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Added a link to two short input files and the results file that should be achieved. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spyne:

```
from spyne.model.primitive import *
from spyne.model.complex import *

class GpsInfo(ComplexModel):
    UTC = DateTime
    Latitude = Double
    Longitude = Double
    DopplerTime = Double
    Quality = Unicode
    HDOP = Unicode
    Altitude = Double
    Speed = Double
    Heading = Double
    Estimated = Boolean

class Header(ComplexModel):
    Name = Unicode
    Time = DateTime
    SeqNo = Integer

class CTrailData(ComplexModel):
    index = UnsignedInteger
    gpsInfo = GpsInfo
    Header = Header

class CTrail(ComplexModel):
    LastError = AnyXml
    MaxTrial = Integer
    Trail = Array(CTrailData)

from lxml import etree
from spyne.util.xml import *

file_1 = get_xml_as_object(etree.fromstring(open('file1').read()), CTrail)
file_2 = get_xml_as_object(etree.fromstring(open('file2').read()), CTrail)
file_1.Trail.extend(file_2.Trail)
file_1.Trail.sort(key=lambda x: x.index)

elt = get_object_as_xml(file_1, no_namespace=True)
print etree.tostring(elt, pretty_print=True)
```

While doing this, Spyne also converts the data fields from string to their native Python formats as well, so it'll be much easier for you to work with the data from this xml document.

Also, if you don't mind using the latest version from git, you can do e.g.:

```
class GpsInfo(ComplexModel):
    # (...)
    doppler_time = Double(sub_name="DopplerTime")
    # (...)
```

so that you can get data from the CamelCased tags without having to violate PEP8.

Comment: This appears to work somewhat, however, there is some data loss from this code. `<Header>` and its contained elements `Name`, `Time`, `SeqNo` information will be lost from this.

Comment: Whoops, I'd forgotten to add Header as a child to CTrailData. Fixed.

Comment: This also (as far as I can see - I haven't implemented it yet), will not sort by index of each point. The output should be `<index>1</index>` followed by `<index>1</index>` from the second file and so forth. This as I see it, will (smartly) append `file2` to `file1`.

Comment: Well, you do it the usual way. ``Trail`` is a regular python list. see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Use lxml.objectify:

```
from lxml import etree, objectify

obj_1 = objectify.fromstring(open('file1').read())
obj_2 = objectify.fromstring(open('file2').read())
obj_1.Trail.CTrailData.extend(obj_2.Trail.CTrailData)
# .sort() won't work as objectify's lists are not regular python lists.
obj_1.Trail.CTrailData = sorted(obj_1.Trail.CTrailData, key=lambda x: x.index)

print etree.tostring(obj_1, pretty_print=True)
```

It doesn't do the additional conversion work that the Spyne variant does, but for your use case, that might be enough.